# phpExcel TextValueBinder Don't understand why I need it

Tags: csv, phpexcel

I have the below code that I had to implement for .csv files so leading zeros would be preserved in files that I read. I did NOT have to do this for .xlsx files.

Why do .csv files need to have a TextValueBinder, but .xlsx files do NOT? CSV files are just plain text so I am wondering why phpExcel removes the leading zeros without a TextValueBinder.

Here is the code:

```
function file_to_obj_php_excel($inputFileName)
{
    $CI =& get_instance();      
    if ($CI->config->item('spreadsheet_format') == 'XLSX')
    {
        $objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();
    }
    else
    {
        $objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_CSV();
        PHPExcel_Cell::setValueBinder(new TextValueBinder());
    }

    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

    return $objPHPExcel;
}

class TextValueBinder implements PHPExcel_Cell_IValueBinder
{
    public function bindValue(PHPExcel_Cell $cell, $value = null) 
    {
        $cell->setValueExplicit($value, PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel xls and xlsx files have specific datatyping and formatting defined alongside the data itself: csv files do not, they're purely raw data. So PHPExcel uses a value binder to specify datatyping and additional formatting and styling based on the values loaded from a csv file, in exactly the same way that the import wizard does when you load a csv file into MS Excel.

For example, this allows the Reader to recognise numeric values, and store the data as a typed number; or to recognise date or time strings, and convert to an MS Excel timestamp with a number format mask... exactly as MS Excel itself does when you load a csv file.

And it also allows you to define custom binders to change this behaviour to suit your own requirements

Comment: Got it! Glad I ran across the error before customers got the code. Do you think my code above will always cause phpExcel to always read it as plain text?

Comment: It should do, because you're explicitly setting the data as datatype string